# z transform of unit ramp - variations

Tags: control-theory, z-transform, linear-control

I wonder about the z transform for each of these sequences:
$$ h_{n} = {1,2,3,4,5,6,...,\infty}$$

versus

$$x_{n} = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,\infty}$$

where n = 0 to $\infty$ in both cases.

My understanding:
$$H(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$$

$$x_{n} = h(n+1) = zH(z) - zh(0) = \frac{z^{2}}{(z-1)^{2}} - z$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I got those mixed up it seems.

Comment: I think this is correct??? Oher way around because unit ramp always starts from zero.
$$X(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$$

$$H(z) = x(n+1) = zX(z) - zx(0) = \frac{z^{2}}{(z-1)^{2}}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, we identify both sequences like tihis:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n} &= \underbrace{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,\infty}_{ramp}=n\\
h_{n} &= \underbrace{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,\infty}_{shifted\,\, ramp}=n+1\\
\end{align}
$$

If we go through the Z-transform definition, we have, on your case, these two sums:

$$
\begin{align}
X(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{kz^{-k}} & H(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1)z^{-k}} 
\end{align}
$$

Looking at a Z-transform table we have:

$$X(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$$

Then we can open up $H(z)$:

$$
\begin{align}
H(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1)z^{-k}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{kz^{-k}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{z^{-k}}\\
&=X(z)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1^{k}z^{-k}}\\
&=\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}+\frac{z}{z-1}\\
&=\frac{z(z-1)+z(z-1)^{2}}{\left(z-1\right)^3}\\
&=\frac{z(z-1)(1+z-1)}{\left(z-1\right)^3}\\
&=\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^{2}}
\end{align}
$$

Which is exactly the same as using the time-shift property shown in the comments and your own question!